# Java: Binary form representation

Tags: binary

How does -1 in Java translate to 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 in binary? I understand that Java uses bytecode and that bytecode converts the highest bit to 1 if the value is negative. But how does -1 gets to the binary form as stated above?

Comment: What you are looking for is called '2s compliment'.

Comment: Till -127 we can use 2s complement to get the binary representation. How do you get -128 for a byte?

Comment: -128 is `1000 0000`. The most negative number is the exception to 2's compliment. The 2s compliment wikipedia has a section talking about the most negative number.

Comment: By my understanding, the highest order bit denotes that this is a negative number, and other zeroes make it 0. So ideally it should be -0. How do you get it as -128.

Comment: No need to have 0 and -0, so we assign 1000 000 to -128.

Answer (score 0):

@user1793823, you may use Windows 10 Calculator [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUPyZ.png)] to fiddle with binary representations. Or, you may try to google for online calculators, such as https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/twos-complement

Comment: Hi Marcus, windows 10 calculator does not have byte representation. The online omnicalculator is helpful in understanding how to calculate int(decimal value) from a signed binary, but what I needed is to understand how to convert the following-

byte b = (byte) 0xf1;

By printing b, I am getting -15. How to achieve that?

Comment: Windows 10 calculator DOES have a byte representation. Try switching the mode to Developer, please. To see how 0xF1 translates to -15, refer to this link. After the calculator, there is some text on base conversion. https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html?x=f1